# Wrong bind techniques?

Tags: javascript

Did you ever think about what exactly `bind` does and if `bind` can be overused?

This is model of the object that is considered as a bad practise *(example A)*:

```
var A = function() {
    this.foo = "foo";
    this.bar = function () {
        console.log("bar");
    };
};
```

This is *same* object written better:

```
var A = function() {
    this.foo = "foo";
};

A.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log("bar");
};
```

Function `bar` is not declared over and over for each instance of `A`. Now look at the following snippet:

```
function origin() {
    console.log(this.toString() + " is who I am");
};

var listOfBindedF = [];

var dummyObject = {};

for(var i = 0; i<100;i++) {
    listOfBindedF.push(origin.bind(dummyObject));
}
```

With each bind usage, I declared new function didnt I? A lot of libs, frameworks and engines uses bind in its core. Not just for async calls, where it is really hard to go without bind, but literally everywhere, custom inheritance is good example.

I did short test to check it on my own.

- Array with 100k length and full of references to `origin` eats
  ~465kB.
- Array with 200k length, 100k references to `origin` and 100k
  references to `dummyObject` eats ~1.1MB.
- Array with 100k length full
  of `origin.bind(dummyObject)` eats ~9.5MB.

So is there any `bind` performance impact on javascript apps we are doing with these frameworks/libs? Is the impact noticable? Isnt it similar to *example A*?

Answer (score 2):

First off, this is a function declaration

```
function foo() {
}
```

and this is a function expression

```
var foo = function() {};
```

Your two `A`s are different. Imagine the following code:

```
function A(foo) {
  this.bar = function() {
               console.log(foo);
             };
}
```

This keeps `foo` private and still allows `bar` to access it, something not possible with the prototype version of `A`.

As for the memory issue: Each `function` object takes up some memory, obviously. A function expression always creates a new object. Creating 100 instances of `A` would create 100 function objects assigned to `bar` using your first example.

A function declaration creates an instance when its surrounding scope is entered. So 100 instances of `A` would still create 100 instances of `bar` in this case:

```
function A(foo) {
  function bar() {
    console.log(foo); 
  }
  this.bar = bar;
}
```

`bind` also creates a new function object that needs even more memory (it has to store a reference to the original function, the value for `this` etc.)

Using `bind` has an impact, but I doubt that that will ever lead to performance problems in your app. FWIW: Calling `bar` in your first example for `A` is faster then calling it in your second one, because it's not necessary to go up the prototype chain.

Please note that `bind` can be used for currying as well, making it a versatile tool:

```
function log(message) {
  console.log(message);
}

var logHello = log.bind(null, 'Hello');
logHello(); // prints 'Hello' to the console
```

Conclusion: Use the tool that's best suited for a task.